# Azure Logic Apps: receive encrypted email

Tags: azure-logic-apps, smime

I need to receive encrypted email from a shared mailbox. I want to decrypt the mail, check the signature and then extract the attachments.
It sounds like this is not supported out of the box by Logic Apps (receiving email ok but not decryption), am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not possible out of the box with Azure Logic Apps. But, there is a workaround to your requirement.

1. Use Azure Functions in your Logic App orchestration to decrypt your Email
2. Also, Azure Functions can be used to check the Signature. This process is also not possible out of the box (considering all the test cases). Refer this blog and tweak it to your scenario https://www.serverless360.com/blog/extract-email-attachment-with-microsoft-flow

P.S: PGP encryption and decryption is on top user voice list.